# Import Firebase custom events to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

First of all, I should say that I know nothing about SQL. I have around 53 custom events on Firebase, under `item_name` and `location`. 
I linked the account to Bigquery to play on the sandbox, basically to learn how to use. I've linked yesterday and today those custom events aren't showing at BigQuery. 
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6318765?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512):

> After you link a project to BigQuery, the first daily export of events
>   creates a corresponding dataset in the associated BigQuery project.
>   Then, each day, raw event data for each linked app populates a new
>   daily table in the associated dataset, and raw event data is streamed
>   into a separate intraday BigQuery table in real-time.

This means that everyday collected data will be streamed to the appevents_intraday_ temporary table in BigQuery. This table collects all the data from the current day. Then, this data will be moved to its appevents_ permanent table at the end of the day and the temporary `intraday` table will be cleaned up.

I recommend you to take a look for the following [Firebase post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, I read the docs, but those custom events aren't showing on the tables.
Ley me see if I can be more clear..lol
On Firebase I click on Events. My custom events are under select_content > item_name / location
When I click on item_name/location I'm redirected to a page on Firebase that shows my custom events.

Comment: Custom parameters are included in the data exported to BigQuery beginning on the date you link your Firebase project to BigQuery. The export to BigQuery is not retroactive: no custom-parameter data from before you create the link is exported. If you found, that it's not working in your case I would suggest you to fill in bug report [here](https://firebase.google.com/support). Thanks!